# How should we handle Magento questions on Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion

Since magento.se is now in public beta, how should we handle question about Magento in other se websites?

I mean, if a good question about Magento is asked on Stackoverflow, do we have to flag it as *off topic* and/or ask a mod to be migrate the question to magento.se ?

Comment: It looks like there has been a number of migrated questions from SO now.

Comment: @sonassi Which ones ?

Comment: From looking at my fancy moderator panel :) http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1182/how-to-recalculate-shipping-costs-in-magento-one-page-checkout http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/magento-what-is-the-customer-payment-entity-type-used-for http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/magento-can-the-associated-products-of-a-configurable-product-inherit-details http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/set-individual-options-out-of-stock-in-magento

Comment: @sonassi that have been done by moderator which is not really my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Migration should be rare for a beta site, particularly during the early days.

That said, if you see a good question going unanswered on SO - especially if it's not strictly programming-related - go ahead and leave a comment there noting that such a question would be welcomed here as well. For instance,

> While questions on Stack Overflow are expected to be about programming in some fashion, [magento.se] welcomes any question on the use of Magento.

(the bit in brackets will automatically expand to a link here)

Be careful not to flag or spam questions that are already well-answered and clearly on-topic; this will tend to irritate both the askers and the moderators.

Comment: All right, thanks !

Comment: You know that "magento.se" links to some Finnish magento developer's website, right?

Comment: Try it in brackets in a comment, @buttle [magento.se]